# read a vector of json in athena

Tags: sql, json, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena

I have the following data structure in a file:

```
[
{
id:12313,
field1: "dfsf"
field2:[
      {
        "type": "Patient",
        "id": "p123fwe",
        "info": 
          {
            "system": "email",
            "value": "sample@gmail.com"
          }
        ,
        "communication": [
          {
            "system": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "EHP",
                  "code": "en_GB",
                  "display": "en_GB"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
{
id:987545,
field1: "dfsf"
field2:[
      {
        "type": "Patient",
        "id": "p123fwe",
        "info": 
          {
            "system": "email",
            "value": "sample@gmail.com"
          }
        ,
        "communication": [
          {
            "system": {
              "coding": [
                {
                  "system": "EHP",
                  "code": "en_GB",
                  "display": "en_GB"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
]
```

I need to create a table from this file in athena, but it is impossible. I am trying to go little by little...for example, I have been trying to start by getting the fields id, field1, field2.type and field2.id . Keeping in mind that I am trying to get each field of the JSON to be a column of my table, the closest I have gotten to achieve my goal is:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (
 data array <
    struct<
    id : STRING,
    field1: STRING,
    field2: ARRAY<
        struct<
            type: STRING,
            id: STRING
        >
     >
    >
>
)
LOCATION 's3://h2020-shapes-dev/datalakehouse/00-raw-tier/FHIR/glucose'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

But this just returns the whole json in one column, and it saves it as a really big string...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

1. It should be no upper array if you want to read it as separate rows.
2. Each Json object (struct) should be in single line.

Remove array [], put struct objects each in single line in file and define table like this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (
 data struct<
    id : STRING,
    field1: STRING,
    field2: ARRAY<
        struct<
            type: STRING,
            id: STRING
        >
     >
    >
)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
LOCATION ...
...
```

Read more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/parsing-JSON.html

Comment: i can't, i get the file sent like that....I have been told not to change it one bit